# How to get rid of reduce-reduce bison

Tags: bison, yacc, reduce-reduce-conflict

my code is the following:

```
%%
%token blablabla
%%

expresion:  operand
            operand '-' expresion
           |operand '+' expresion
           | '(' expresion ')'  /*Conflict line*/
;

/*terminal symbols */operand: IDENTIFIER                { printf (" %s ", $1) ; } 
                             | NUMBER                   { printf (" %s ", $1) ; }
       ;
```

I get 3 reduce/reduce warnings when compiling (even though the code runs correctly). How can I get rid of these warnings?

Comment: PS: the reduce-reduce come from the second sentence, when i put something else, they do not appear.

Comment: How does the production tree terminate? I.e., what is your terminal expression?

Comment: I'm rusty on Bison, but I remember reduce/reduce errors happen when two or more rules can apply to the same input. Your code runs correctly because Bison just chooses the first rule that works and goes with it. Can you show us what you're trying to parse?

Comment: Those rules, by it self, don't have any problem. Maybe you could check .output file that bison generates and see what rules are involved on the conflict.

Comment: What's your definition of `operand`?

Comment: the definition of operand is quite trivial, it just prints a number or an identifier. Anyway, here is its code:
operand:    IDENTIFIER        { printf (" %s ", $1) ; } 
           | NUMBER               { printf (" %s ", $1) ; }
           ;

Comment: @BobDalgleish it terminates with, for instance a-(3), a-3 or a-((a-3))

Comment: @g_tec whats that file you are talking about? when i compile it, i only get the .tab.c and the executable file

Comment: @CocoaDog im trying to parse something like a-(3) and so on. Then i would print something else, but that actually doesnt matter at all, it does it right the problem is that i get this warning.

Comment: The main problem with your code is that it can never match anything because there is no non-recursive rule for `expresion`. However that's not the problem you described, so I have to assume that the code you posted here is not your real code. So please fix that.

Comment: @sepp2k yes you are right, is a simplification. i have another line with |operand '+' expression and the important part i was missing is the rule expression: operand, im editing it now

Comment: @user1920212 Your code as-is (after replacing the `%token blabla` bit with something sensible) still can't match anything (and compiling it with bison will give you an error message to that effect). After fixing the missing `|`, which I assume was a typo, it compiles fine without conflicts. So, unless you were lying about getting conflicts, this is still not your real code. PS: Your + and - operators are right-associative when they should be left-associative - though that wouldn't cause any conflicts, just wrong results.

Comment: @user1920212 Compile it with a `-v`flag on bison. It will be createad a `.output` file. There, you can see what rules are involved on the conflict as I said before.

Comment: @sepp2k if you can, please tell me your email and i send you the whole code so you can see the error that im talking about

Comment: @user1920212 I'd much prefer if you managed to come up with a small example that bison actually accepts without error and produces the conflicts you're asking about (so no `%% %token blabla`, no missing `|` - something that you've actually run through bison to verify that it contains the conflicts and no other errors).

Answer (score 1):

Methinks you want

```
     %left '-' '+'


     expression : operand
                 | expression '-' expression
                 | expression '+' expression
                 | '(' expression ')'
```

Comment: While that should work, there's no reason why encoding the precedence in the grammar rather than using `%left` should lead to conflicts. This will fix a bunch of other issues with the OP's code, but whatever caused the conflicts in the real code, probably was not due to a lack of `%left`s.

Comment: That does not work for this case, and @sepp2k of course it is the real code, not the whole code as it does not have sense to copy and paste 400 lines of code where the rest is totally independent modules.

Comment: @user1920212 As I already told you, the code you posted here contains errors that have nothing to do with your conflicts and after fixing those errors, the code works fine (except for the unrelated problems I already mentioned) without conflicts. So, no, thus is not your real code nor is it representative of your real code.